# Where can I exchange GBP to Monero (XMR)?

Tags: exchange

Does anyone know where can I exchange GBP to Monero (XMR)?

Thank you.

Regards,

Chris

Comment: You are best off buying bitcoin, or euro, and exchanging for xmr on Kraken or other exchange

Answer (score 1):

You could try localmonero: https://localmonero.co

But there aren't many GBP sellers there with very high sell records or reputations, so you may be better off buying bitcoin first, as suggested already, then send those to an exchange (such as Poloniex, Kraken, Bitfinex, or one of many others) and then exchange them for Monero there.